# actionPerformed skip a step

Tags: java, swing, graphics, actionlistener, paintcomponent

I want everytime i click on the button "bouton" to execute the function

boutonPane.Panel2(h, ....) which is supposed to display h circles. So i want 2 then 3 then 4, then 5... circles.

The problem is that it is not displaying the step with number 4. I see the function is called in the console but on the screen it does really 2, (press button) 3, (press button) 5, (press button)9. I dont see 4. I dont see 6,7,8.. Could you tell me what is the problem please? Here is the code:

```
 public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        int lg = 1000; int lrg = 700;
        int h = 2;

        Panel b = new  Panel(); 

        private JButton btn = new JButton("Start");

        JButton bouton = new JButton();

        private JPanel container = new JPanel();

        public Window(){ 
            this.setTitle("Animation");
            this.setSize(300, 300);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            container.setBackground(Color.white);
            container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel top = new JPanel(); 

            btn.addActionListener(this); 
            top.add(btn);
            container.add(top);
            this.setContentPane(container);
            this.setVisible(true); 
      }

      public void Window2()
      {

            System.out.println("windows2");

            this.setTitle("ADHD");
            this.setSize(lg, lrg);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 

            bouton.addActionListener(this); 


            if(h<11)
            {
                Panel boutonPane = new Panel();
                boutonPane.Panel2(h, Color.BLUE ,lg, lrg, this.getGraphics());

                System.out.println("draw"+h);

                boutonPane.add(bouton);

                this.add(boutonPane);
                this.setContentPane(boutonPane);
                this.revalidate();
                this.repaint();

            }


            this.setVisible(true);  

      }




      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
      { 
          if((JButton)e.getSource()==btn) 
          { 
              System.out.println("pressed0");
              Window2(); 

          } 
          if((JButton)e.getSource()==bouton) 
          { 
              h++;
              System.out.println("pressed"+h);
              Window2(); 

          } 
      }
    }
```

Here is a the Panel class:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel
{ 

    int m;
    int i=1;

    int a=0, b=0, tremp=0;
    Color cc;
    int lgi, lrgi;
    int [] ta;
    int [] tb;

    Graphics gi;

    int u=0;

    Panel()
    {

    }

    public void Panel2(int n, Color c, int lg, int lrg, Graphics g){
        m=n;
        cc=c;
        gi=g;
        lgi=lg;
        lrgi=lrg;
        ta = new int [n]; ta[0]=0;
        tb = new int [n]; tb[0]=0;

    }

    public void paintComponent( final Graphics gr){

        gr.setColor(Color.red);

        for(int it=0; it<m;it++)
        {
            ta[it]=100*it;
            tb[it]=100*it;
            gr.fillOval(ta[it],tb[it], 150, 150);
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: I hope it is edited correctly now. Does anyone has an answer to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   int lg = 1000;
   int lrg = 700;
   int h = 2;

   Panel b = new Panel();

   private JButton btn = new JButton("Start");

   JButton bouton = new JButton();

   private JPanel container = new JPanel();
   Panel boutonPane = new Panel();

   public Window()
   {
      this.setTitle("Animation");
      this.setSize(300, 300);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      container.setBackground(Color.white);
      container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      JPanel top = new JPanel();

      btn.addActionListener(this);
      top.add(btn);
      container.add(top);
      this.setContentPane(container);
      this.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void Window2()
   {

      System.out.println("windows2");

      this.setTitle("ADHD");
      this.setSize(lg, lrg);
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

      bouton.addActionListener(this);

      if (h < 11)
      {

         boutonPane.Panel2(h, Color.BLUE, lg, lrg, this.getGraphics());

         System.out.println("draw" + h);

         boutonPane.add(bouton);

         this.add(boutonPane);
         this.setContentPane(boutonPane);
         updateWindow2();

      }

      this.setVisible(true);

   }

   public void updateWindow2()
   {
      boutonPane.Panel2(h, Color.BLUE, lg, lrg, this.getGraphics());
      this.revalidate();
      this.repaint();
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      if ((JButton) e.getSource() == btn)
      {
         System.out.println("pressed0");
         Window2();

      }
      if ((JButton) e.getSource() == bouton)
      {
         h++;
         System.out.println("pressed" + h);
         updateWindow2();

      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Test t = new Test();
   }
}
```

What you did wrong was adding a new BoutonPane every time you clicked the button. The next time you clicked the button, you didn't click ONE button, but TWO buttons, adding two more boutonPanes, and two more buttons. This multiplies very quickly.

What I did was the following:

- make boutonPane a class member variable
- call window2() only once
- create a method updateWindow2() for updating the circles. Call that method from window2() and actionPerformed().

Comment: Accepting the answer would be greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: I made a simple version of Panel but with the real one that I use it doesn't work. I could send the code but it uses other classes and picture of the project. What would you suggest me to do? to send everything but the pictures?

Answer (score 2):

> "But would you have an idea of another, correct, way to do what I want please?"

- You should only have *one* panel for the circles. There's *absolutely* no need to keep creating new panel.
- Use a `List` for [`Ellipse2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) objects. Just loop through them in the `paintComponent` method.
- When you want to add a new circle, just add a new `Ellipse2D` object to the `List` and call `repaint()`

Here's an example.

**NOTE** Accept Gijs Overvliet's answer, as his was the one that answered your problem. I just wanted to share some insight.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class EllipseList extends JPanel {

    private static final int D_W = 700;
    private static final int D_H = 500;
    private static final int CIRCLE_SIZE = 50;

    private List<Ellipse2D> circles;
    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;

    private CirclePanel circlePanel = new CirclePanel();

    public EllipseList() {
        circles = new ArrayList<>();

        JButton jbtAdd = createButton();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(jbtAdd, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(circlePanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Add");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                circles.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, CIRCLE_SIZE, CIRCLE_SIZE));
                x += CIRCLE_SIZE * 0.75;
                y += CIRCLE_SIZE * 0.75;
                circlePanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
            for (Ellipse2D circle : circles) {

                g2.fill(circle);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new EllipseList();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i made a simple version of my class Panel to be able to publish the code on the website. Actually, even with Gijs answer, it is not working with my real panel. How should I do? I could send you the code of my real Panel but it uses other classes and pictures of the project. Maybe i could send you the folder of the project?